# Reduce Is Not Running In MapReduce Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce, mapper

I try to use MapReduce in Hadoop with Windows 11 and Python. My mapper function complete successfully, but the reducer function does not seem to be running or making progress. I got Map 100% and Reduce 0%. I waited for a long time, but it didn't make any progress.

This is my Mapper function

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split(", ")
    try:
        print('%s|%s' % (words[0].strip(), words[1]))
    except:
        pass
```

This is my Reducer function

```
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

current_word = None
current_good = ""
word = None

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    word, good = line.split('|')
    if current_word == word:
        current_good = current_good + ", " + good
    else:
        if current_word:
            print('%s|%s' % (current_word, current_good))
        current_good = good
        current_word = word

if current_word == word:
    print('%s|%s' % (current_word, current_good))
```

This is my data in txt
"
ani,pensil
budi,pensil
ani,buku
dodi,penggaris
"

[My Reduce is not running and still in 0%.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j3CG.png)

How to fix this so I can get Reduce 100% and my MapReduce function success?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to modify your reducer code. you check if current_word == word after the loop ends, but word is not updated in the last iteration. because of this , the last key-value pair is not processed correctly.